# Copy Range and Sort the copied cells

Tags: vba, excel

I'm making a code in order to copy data from a database in a new list. This with the purpose of using this data in a .txt export file in another program.

I have a large list with names and data next to it. And I would like to copy the names with the associated data in a new workbook. This data also needs to be sorted in **'depth'** in order to get the result that I need for the export file.

I hope somebody can help me with this. At this moment I managed to get a list of the names and the start and end row of each name in a new workbook. I think this helps me with getting the data sorted.

Now I want to expand this code so that I can copy the data that I need.
I included a picture where you can see how my database looks. This is indicated in the black square. And in the red square you see how I want the result list to look like.
I hope somebody can help me with this!
[Database and Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CspkI.png)

This is the code that I have until now:

```
Option Explicit

Sub RowCount()
Dim Oldstatusbar As Boolean
Dim DOF As Integer, Counter As Integer, Row_Copied As Integer
Dim CurrentMin As Long, StartRow As Long, StartColumn As Long
Dim OutputColumn As Long, OutputRow As Long
Dim Borehole As String, Start_Row As String, End_Row As String, Output As String
Dim CurrentName As String
Dim rng As RANGE, Cell As RANGE, brh As RANGE
Dim wbMain As Workbook, wbWellsRowCount As Workbook
Dim wsLog As Worksheet, wsSheet1 As Worksheet, wsSheet2 As Worksheet
Dim HCdatabase2 As Variant

Oldstatusbar = Application.DisplayStatusBar



Set wbMain = Workbooks("HCdatabase2.xlsm")
Set wsLog = wbMain.Sheets("Log")

DOF = 1
Counter = 1
Row_Copied = 0

wsLog.Select
StartColumn = 1
StartRow = 1
wsLog.Cells(StartRow + DOF, StartColumn).End(xlDown).Select

Set rng = wsLog.RANGE(wsLog.Cells(StartRow + DOF, StartColumn), wsLog.Cells(StartRow + DOF, StartColumn).End(xlDown))
CurrentName = wsLog.Cells(StartRow + DOF, StartColumn).Value
CurrentMin = Cells(StartRow + DOF, StartColumn).Row


Set wbWellsRowCount = Workbooks.Add
wbWellsRowCount.SaveAs "H:\Petrel\2016 Youri Kickken - Stage - HC Shows\VBA\Code Set-up\VBA-DATABASE\wbWellsRowCount.xls"

Set wsSheet1 = wbWellsRowCount.Sheets("Sheet1")
wsSheet1.Select
OutputColumn = 1
OutputRow = DOF + 1
wsSheet1.Cells(OutputRow, OutputColumn).Value = CurrentName
wsSheet1.Cells(OutputRow, OutputColumn + 1).Value = CurrentMin

wsSheet1.Cells(1, 1).Name = "Borehole"
wsSheet1.Cells(1, 2).Name = "Start_Row"
wsSheet1.Cells(1, 3).Name = "End_Row"
wsSheet1.Cells(1, 4).Name = "Output"

ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
Set wsSheet2 = wbWellsRowCount.Sheets("Sheet2")




For Each Cell In rng

If Cell.Value <> CurrentName Then

    wsSheet1.Cells(OutputRow, OutputColumn + 2).Value = Cell.Row - 1
    CurrentName = Cell.Value
    CurrentMin = Cell.Row
    OutputRow = OutputRow + 1
    wsSheet1.Cells(OutputRow, OutputColumn).Value = CurrentName
    wsSheet1.Cells(OutputRow, OutputColumn + 1).Value = CurrentMin

    wsSheet1.Cells(Counter + DOF, "D").Value = Counter
    Counter = Counter + 1
End If

 Next Cell
 Set Cell = rng.End(xlDown)
 wsSheet1.Cells(OutputRow, OutputColumn + 2).Value = Cell.Row
 wsSheet1.Cells(Counter + DOF, "D").Value = Counter


End If
Next Cell



wbWellsRowCount.Close True
RANGE("A1").Select
ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = RANGE("A1").Row

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayStatusBar = Oldstatusbar
End Sub
```

Comment: You can see in the picture that the 2 different classes are sorted by depth in the results.

Comment: Did you think about using a Class ?it will be much easier to sort it out, and much faster for large sets of data

Comment: Yeah I did, but the 2 class columns are different, which means they represent two different variables. Therefore I need both columns.

Comment: , anyway, during the weekend I wrote an answer (see below) that uses a Class. on the tests I conducted with the samples of data you provided I got the results you asked for, feel free to test it yourself

Comment: Thank you! I will try the code and see if it fits my purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can adapt and use this code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    With Workbooks("Data").Worksheets("Depths") '<--| change 'Workbooks("Data").Worksheets("Depths")' with your actual workbook and worksheet name
        With .Range("A2", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)) '<--| refer to column "A" cells from row 2 down to last non empty one
            .Offset(.Rows.Count).value = .value '<--| duplicate names down column "A"
            .Offset(.Rows.Count, 1).value = .Offset(, 3).value '<--| duplicate 2nd Depth column down 1st Depth column
            .Offset(.Rows.Count, 4).value = .Offset(, 4).value '<--| duplicate Class_2 column down itself
            .Offset(, 4).ClearContents '<--| clear original Class_2 column
            .Offset(, 3).EntireColumn.Delete '<--| delete 2nd Depth column, no longer needed
            With .Offset(, 1).Resize(2 * .Rows.Count) '<--|refer to Depth column (the only one remained)
                If WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(.Cells) > 0 Then .SpecialCells(XlCellType.xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete '<--| delete empty values rows
            End With
        End With
        With .Range("A2", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).Resize(, 4) '<--| refer to all data: columns "A:D" from row 2 down to column "A" last non empty one
            .Sort key1:=.Cells(1, 1), order1:=xlAscending, key2:=.Cells(1, 2), order2:=xlAscending, header:=xlNo, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, DataOption1:=xlSortNormal, DataOption2:=xlSortNormal '<--| sort it!
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

so that once you have your original data already copied in the *final place* as per your "Starting Point database" example, you just:

- change `Workbooks("Data").Worksheets("Depths")` with your actual *final place* workbook and worksheet references
- run it and you'll have the final data arrangement

Comment: Thank you very much for your code! I tried It and it almost does what I want. The only problem is that the second class column is duplicated below itself, while it should be cut and put next to the copied second depth column.

Comment: With this I mean that the second class column is duplicated and this means with sorting the data the second class column is corrupted by its duplication while it should be cut and pasted at first.

Comment: no cut and paste, just a `ClearContents` after replicating values. see edited answer where I just added `.Offset(, 4).ClearContents` right after `.Offset(.Rows.Count, 4).value = .Offset(, 4).value`

Answer (score 0):

I hope I didn't overkill it, but your post raised a light-bulb for me, as I thought of defining and using a **cDepth** `Class`.

The following Sub (your code, mostly) does the following things:

1) Scans the entire **wsLog** worksheet, and organizes the data in **cDepth** **Class** (array).

2) Sorts the **Depths_Arr** (from `cDepth Class`) according to Name and then by Depth).

3) Copies the data back (in my code I am copying the data to **Columns H:K** in the same worksheet) - you can modify the target easily.

```
Option Explicit

' Class Array CDates Variables to store all Series data
Public Current_Depth                    As CDepth
Public Depths_Arr()                     As CDepth

Sub RowCount()

Dim Oldstatusbar As Boolean
Dim DOF As Integer, Counter As Integer, Row_Copied As Integer
Dim CurrentMin As Long, StartRow As Long, StartColumn As Long
Dim OutputColumn As Long, OutputRow As Long
Dim Borehole As String, Start_Row As String, End_Row As String, Output As String
Dim CurrentName As String
Dim rng As Range, Cell As Range, brh As Range
Dim wbMain As Workbook, wbWellsRowCount As Workbook
Dim wsLog As Worksheet, wsSheet1 As Worksheet, wsSheet2 As Worksheet
Dim HCdatabase2 As Variant

Dim LastRow As Long, lRow As Long
Dim ClassIndex  As Long


Oldstatusbar = Application.DisplayStatusBar

Set wbMain = Workbooks("HCdatabase2.xlsm")
Set wsLog = wbMain.Sheets("Log")

DOF = 1
StartColumn = 1
StartRow = 1
ClassIndex = 0

LastRow = wsLog.Cells(wsLog.Rows.Count, StartColumn).End(xlUp).Row

For lRow = StartRow + DOF To LastRow
    Set Current_Depth = New CDepth

    ' organize data in Current_Depth array
    With Current_Depth
        If wsLog.Cells(lRow, 2) > 0 Then
            .cName = wsLog.Cells(lRow, StartColumn)
            .Depth = wsLog.Cells(lRow, StartColumn + 1)
            .ClassVal = wsLog.Cells(lRow, StartColumn + 2)
            .ClassType = 1

            ReDim Preserve Depths_Arr(0 To ClassIndex)
            Set Depths_Arr(ClassIndex) = Current_Depth
            ClassIndex = ClassIndex + 1
            Set Current_Depth = Nothing
        End If

    End With

    Set Current_Depth = New CDepth
    With Current_Depth
        If wsLog.Cells(lRow, 4) > 0 Then
            .cName = wsLog.Cells(lRow, StartColumn)
            .Depth = wsLog.Cells(lRow, StartColumn + 3)
            .ClassVal = wsLog.Cells(lRow, StartColumn + 4)
            .ClassType = 2

            ReDim Preserve Depths_Arr(0 To ClassIndex)
            Set Depths_Arr(ClassIndex) = Current_Depth
            ClassIndex = ClassIndex + 1
            Set Current_Depth = Nothing
        End If

    End With

Next lRow

' variables for bubble-sort
Dim tmp_DepthArr                        As CDepth
Dim i, j                                As Long

' sort Depth array >> first by Name >> second by Depth
For i = LBound(Depths_Arr) To UBound(Depths_Arr) - 1
    For j = i + 1 To UBound(Depths_Arr)
        ' first sort >> by Name
        If Depths_Arr(i).cName > Depths_Arr(j).cName Then
            Set tmp_DepthArr = Depths_Arr(i)
            Set Depths_Arr(i) = Depths_Arr(j)
            Set Depths_Arr(j) = tmp_DepthArr
            Set tmp_DepthArr = Nothing

            Exit For
        End If

        ' second sort >> by Depth
        If Depths_Arr(i).cName = Depths_Arr(j).cName And Depths_Arr(i).Depth > Depths_Arr(j).Depth Then
            ' switch position between cMilesones class array elements according to Plan Date
            Set tmp_DepthArr = Depths_Arr(i)
            Set Depths_Arr(i) = Depths_Arr(j)
            Set Depths_Arr(j) = tmp_DepthArr
            Set tmp_DepthArr = Nothing
        End If

    Next j
Next i

' copy sorted Depths Array back to sheet >> Modify target according to your needs
For i = LBound(Depths_Arr) To UBound(Depths_Arr)
    wsLog.Cells(i + 2, StartColumn + 7) = Depths_Arr(i).cName
    wsLog.Cells(i + 2, StartColumn + 8) = Depths_Arr(i).Depth
    wsLog.Cells(i + 2, StartColumn + 8 + Depths_Arr(i).ClassType) = Depths_Arr(i).ClassVal
Next i

End Sub
```

The following ***cDepth*** `Class` is for storing the Table's data in an organized array with the following attributes:
*Name*, *Depth*, *ClassVal* and *ClassType*

***CDepth*** Class code:

```
'private Attributes

Private pName                           As String
Private pDepth                          As Integer
Private pClassVal                       As Integer
Private pClassType                      As Integer

' --- Get/Let Methods ---

Public Property Get cName() As String
    cName = pName
End Property

Public Property Let cName(value As String)
    pName = value
End Property


Public Property Get Depth() As Integer
    Depth = pDepth
End Property

Public Property Let Depth(value As Integer)
    pDepth = value
End Property


Public Property Get ClassVal() As Integer
    ClassVal = pClassVal
End Property

Public Property Let ClassVal(value As Integer)
    pClassVal = value
End Property


Public Property Get ClassType() As Integer
    ClassType = pClassType
End Property

Public Property Let ClassType(value As Integer)
    pClassType = value
End Property
```